# when extending python with c, how do one cope with arbitrary size integers?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, long-integer, arbitrary-precision

The Python/C API manual mentions conversion functions from⁽¹⁾ and to⁽²⁾  void pointers, which seem to be the only way to use arbitrary length python integers in C.
(1) : `PyLong_FromVoidPtr()` and format `0&` with `Py_BuildValue()`
(2) : `PyLong_AsVoidPtr()` and formats `0`, `0&` and `0!` with `PyArg_…Parse…()`

However, I haven't found⁽³⁾ in the manual, any indication about the way to use those void pointers to do whatever in C with those arbitrary long integers.
(3) : I tried a search for «voidptr», «void *» and «0&» but haven't thoroughly read it all yet.

Where can I find information about their inner structure or primitives to compute on them ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, those functions are not to have "a pointer to an arbitrarily large integer", but literally just integer values as `void *` pointer, as in, casted to the type `void *`. See the implementations for [`PyLong_FromVoidPtr`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/longobject.c#L1017-L1032) and [`PyLong_AsVoidPtr`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/longobject.c#L1034-L1063). It's there just to allow you to hold arbitrary pointers within Python, making sure the casting is done correctly.

As far as I can tell, the most practical way get arbitrary long integers from and into Python would be with [`int.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) and [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes). There is actually a internal-ish API [`_PyLong_FromByteArray`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Include/longobject.h#L127-L142) / [`_PyLong_AsByteArray`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Include/longobject.h#L144-L165) for that which you can probably use. See the related question [Python extension - construct and inspect large integers efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18290507/1782792).

Note: Interestingly, there does not seem to be any C API, official or otherwise, to tell the bit or byte length of a Python integer value. In Python there is [`int.bit_length`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length), but it does not appear to map to any publicly available function.

Comment: *there does not seem to be any C API, official or otherwise, to tell the bit or byte length of an integer.*  In C, `sizeof( int )` returns the size of an `int` in bytes.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Sorry, I meant a Python integer value, which can have an arbitrary number of bits (made that clearer now).

Answer (score 2):

There is documentation in `Include/longintrepr.h`:

```
/* Parameters of the integer representation.  There are two different
   sets of parameters: one set for 30-bit digits, stored in an unsigned 32-bit
   integer type, and one set for 15-bit digits with each digit stored in an
   unsigned short.  The value of PYLONG_BITS_IN_DIGIT, defined either at
   configure time or in pyport.h, is used to decide which digit size to use.

   Type 'digit' should be able to hold 2*PyLong_BASE-1, and type 'twodigits'
   should be an unsigned integer type able to hold all integers up to
   PyLong_BASE*PyLong_BASE-1.  x_sub assumes that 'digit' is an unsigned type,
   and that overflow is handled by taking the result modulo 2**N for some N >
   PyLong_SHIFT.  The majority of the code doesn't care about the precise
   value of PyLong_SHIFT, but there are some notable exceptions:

   - long_pow() requires that PyLong_SHIFT be divisible by 5

   - PyLong_{As,From}ByteArray require that PyLong_SHIFT be at least 8

   - long_hash() requires that PyLong_SHIFT is *strictly* less than the number
     of bits in an unsigned long, as do the PyLong <-> long (or unsigned long)
     conversion functions

   - the Python int <-> size_t/Py_ssize_t conversion functions expect that
     PyLong_SHIFT is strictly less than the number of bits in a size_t

   - the marshal code currently expects that PyLong_SHIFT is a multiple of 15

   - NSMALLNEGINTS and NSMALLPOSINTS should be small enough to fit in a single
     digit; with the current values this forces PyLong_SHIFT >= 9

  The values 15 and 30 should fit all of the above requirements, on any
  platform.
*/
```

The length of the `int` is the length of the variable length portion times 15/16 in bits - the digits are either [30 bits in `uint32_t`, `#if PYLONG_BITS_IN_DIGIT == 30`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/22c526394b2ef51b985873ddbfbcc32c16411919/Include/longintrepr.h#L44), else [15 bits in `uint16_t`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/22c526394b2ef51b985873ddbfbcc32c16411919/Include/longintrepr.h#L52); the structure of long object is

```
struct _longobject {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    digit ob_digit[1];
};
```

There is a member [ob_size](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyVarObject) that will tell the size in bytes - so if the `PYLONG_BITS_IN_DIGIT` is 30 the `ob_digit` is an array of `ob_size / sizeof(uint32_t)`  `uint32_t`s, 30 bits are significant in each; otherwise `ob_digit` is an array of `ob_size / sizeof(uint16_t)`  `uint16_t`s, 15 significant bits are stored in each digit.

This is all part of `Include/longintrepr.h`, but they're revealed only `#ifndef Py_LIMITED_API`!